# In Ripple, what exactly is "Hash256"?

Tags: ripple, raw-data, hash, standard

In various places on Ripple Wiki we can see the type `Hash256` (for example [here](https://ripple.com/wiki/Transaction_Format)). What data structure is it exactly? Is it just a 256 byte array, or are there some rules governing this type (and preventing potential misuse)?

Comment: It's a 256 bit hash.

Comment: perhaps the same thing Bitcoin calls Hash256: SHA256(SHA256(x))

Answer (score 2):

The `Hash256` is essentially a `uint256`.  However, after reading through much of the wiki and source, it appears that the `Hash256` type is meant to be a generic, unsigned integer type that can store any form of hash that is larger than 128 bits.

As an example, all hashes mentioned in the [Tree Formats](https://ripple.com/wiki/Ledger_Format#Tree_Formats) portion of the wiki are stored in `Hash256` fields.  Some are 256-bits (I think?) while other mentioned hashes are 160-bit hashes that are padded with 0's.

As an aside, I also noticed that when working with 256-bit hashes, Ripple often uses the first 256-bits of SHA-512 hash.  This is different than the typical SHA-256 hashes that are used with Bitcoin and most other alt-coins.

**NOTE:** I know that a few of the Ripple devs participate in this site.  I would be greatly interested in their input.  The wiki and the source is quite cryptic in design-- almost obfuscated.  I had to follow quite a few rabbit trails to come up with the answer that I've provided.

Comment: Everything you have said above is correct. Except the tree indexes are always actual 256-bit hashes. For example, the 256-bit index for an account root node is the 256-bit hash of a 16-bit "space identifier" followed by the 160-bit account ID.